# Problems with dynamic symbolizer in Chart Symbolizer extension on GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, sld

I have a layer on GeoServer with a time dimension which shows the number of overnight stays for a certain area in a given year. With the Chart Symbolizer extension, I would like to visualise the number of stays as a bar chart on top of the geometry. However, the dynamic symbolizer I am using does not seem to work because it returns the same value in the chart for each year. The SLD code I am using can be found below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/sld/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
  xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld"     xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <NamedLayer>
<Name></Name>
<UserStyle>
  <Name>Charts</Name>
  <FeatureTypeStyle>
    <Rule>
      <PolygonSymbolizer>
        <Fill>
          <CssParameter name="fill">#d3d3d3</CssParameter>
        </Fill>
        <Stroke>
          <CssParameter name="stroke">#000001</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-width">0.26</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </PolygonSymbolizer>
      <PointSymbolizer>
        <Geometry>
          <ogc:Function name="centroid">
            <ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName>
          </ogc:Function>
        </Geometry>
        <Graphic>
          <ExternalGraphic>
            <OnlineResource
              xlink:href="http://chart?cht=bvg&amp;chs=100x100&amp;chd=t:${value/10}&amp;chf=bg,s,FFFFFF00&amp;chxt=x,y&amp;chxr=1,0,35000000" />
            <Format>application/chart</Format>
          </ExternalGraphic>
        </Graphic>
      </PointSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
  </FeatureTypeStyle>
</UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Where am I going wrong?